# Access to User Claims within View Component

Tags: asp.net-core

With this code I can get claim from `user.Claims` in a `Controller`

```
var subClaim = User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

But when try the code in a `ViewComponent` the `User.Claims` not exits.

Is there any way to get `User.Claims` within a `ViewComponent`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `Request.HttpContext.User.Claims`

Also see https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4964#issuecomment-230515330

In this github issue there is another solution:

```
 var user = User as ClaimsPrincipal;
```